# Java heap Error while running R code

Tags: java, r, feature-selection

I'm trying to do a feature selection using the chi.squared function in FSelector package in R.

My dataset is about 132 variables X 192,000 rows.

```
chisquared.fs <- chi.squared(fo,df)
```

where fo contains the class variable: class ~.

I'm getting this error while running the code:

```
Error in .jcall("weka/filters/Filter", "Lweka/core/Instances;", "useFilter",
:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I know it is a Java memory leak error and I have already tried this before calling any libraries:

```
options( java.parameters = "-Xmx6g")
```

Any pointers would be really welcome.

Comment: `tried this before calling any libraries` Did you make the `options` call before _loading_ the libraries?

Comment: Yes I exactly did that.

Comment: 6g may not be enough for a dataset that large.  whats the max memory on your box?  have you tried setting it to that?  also attach with jvisualvm to ensure that the memory is indeed allocated to your java process

Comment: Guys update: I had done what @copeg suggested without restarting R. I restarted R and with the options statement at the beginning before calling the libraries and it worked.  Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guys update: I had done what @copeg suggested without restarting R. I restarted R and with the options statement at the beginning before calling the libraries and it worked. Thanks for your suggestions.